What is the minimum amount of changes to technological development required to delay multi-role fighter aircraft into the 2000s?
How could technological development be minimally affected while still delaying fighter aircraft?
Note that:

Aircraft technological development before when multi-role fighters were developed should not be affected

Computers can't be affected

Land based missile technology can't be affected (Air launched missiles can be though)


The goal is to keep air combat as technologically similar to IRL as possible up until 2000 with the exception of multi-role fighter aircraft not existing and specialized combat aircraft remaining predominant.

Are multi-role fighter aircraft predominant even today? Across the world?

The first mass-produced aircraft which was used in multiple combat roles was the Junkers Ju 88, introduced in 1939. Note 1939. It was originally conceived as a bomber, then adapted as a dive bomber, with added guns it became a fighter-bomber, and finally even used a fighter. When you've got an airframe, strapping on various kinds of stuff is not that hard.

@AlexP let's not overlook the de Havilland Mosquito, introduced just a couple years later (and also the most beautiful pre-jet aircraft ever built, in my absolutely objective opinion). In fact, throughout the war a lot of fighter aircraft doubled as ground attack and light bombers. Realistically, I'm afraid what the OP is asking for is impossible.

Not sure why you're all talking about WW2 aircraft - the Sopwith Camel was an air superiority fighter but could carry bombs for ground attack too.  (It was shifted entirely into the ground attack role as better German fighters that it could not compete with came into service.  Multirole aircraft have existed since the start of combat aviation.

This reads like a speculative discussion prompt not a single specific question intended to establish some fact about a fictional world.

We've hosted a fair number of questions like this and they've traditionally been left open. You do need to be more specific. E.G., name one specific aircraft and use the information that would have delayed that one plane to rationalize delaying them all. As written, there's too much ambiguity (so, VTC:Needs More Focus until you specify just one plane). Note that it's not uncommon for the answer (with so long a date range involved) to be, "it can't be done." In this case, you'd likely have to avoid the entire cold war - which is no small thing.

@AlexP i mean in the sense of the modern conception of multi-role fighter aircraft, not just aircraft filling multiple roles

@JBH "just one plane" isn't really what i'm thinking of, because i am talking about a category of the modern idea of a multirole combat aircraft. Things like the F-15E, F-16s past the first few variants, MIG-29s, the Panavia Tornado, etc. The problem is that i can't just use a specific aircraft, because my world is similar but not the same as earth. So introducing challenges into specific aircraft's development processes will not help because my world's technological development while similar to IRL is not the same.

@JBH - "what could delay the development of multi-role fighters" = bad, "what could delay the development of the MiG-29 that would also apply to other multi-role fighters" = good? Seriously? Tone down the gatekeeping, this is bureaucracy for its own sake, not making the question better.

@KerrAvon2055 - WW2 is the focus because everyone thinks multirole fighter planes were introduced then, which is not correct. Yes, when hearing "multi-role fighter" I hear actually P-47, but it's also not right. True multi-role fighter concept didn't really came until late 60s, with F-16 appearing in early 70s. Everything before were actual air superiority fighters, repurposed for other roles, True, there were attack fighter planes before - but they just were fighters didn't suck as attack planes less than others - though they never were designed as such, and attack planes were not fighters.

@AcePL the F-4 Phantom was intentionally designed as a multirole fighter-bomber in the 50s. As for WW2, I don't think your argument makes things better for the OP, rather it shows that fighter aircraft were already capable ground-attack aircraft even without being explicitly designed for the role, to the extent that the western Allies didn't make a lot of use of dedicated attack aircraft (though the Soviets had the Il-2).

@user111403 - Yes, but kind of. It was to be an attack plane initially, but it's true it was designed as F/A plane, not just F or A. This came because of F-8 becoming next Navy's fighter, so there was no need for another fighter. I didn't go with F-4 because it was ahead of the US Armed Forces doctrine development, which didn't provide a "slot" for multi-role fighter. But I do not contest the point it was actually first one, truly designed as such from grounds-up, but it was still a lot of guesswork involved. Good guesswork, obviously, but... multi-role fighter concept didn't exist then.

@user111403 If you don't understand why focusing on one fighter is better than focusing on the entire class then you really don't understand worldbuilding or why this question has problems. Focusing on (using your example) what had to change about only the USSR is a lot easier than the whole planet. And for a member that's only been around for four months... Stack Exchange is user-moderated and does not embrace the idea of answering every question no matter how poorly formed. Please take the time to read the [help] and work on understanding why there are rules.

@JBH I have in fact read how the site works and what questions are allowed, and I don't appreciate your condescending tone. I'm also familiar with the concept of user moderation, and the problems that come with it. There is no rule, either in the help center or, as far as I see, in practice, that states that asking about a specific member of a class is allowed, but asking about a specific class is not - which is good, because it's a silly rule. But hey, maybe I missed something. So how about a link to the exact page and the exact rule?

But setting aside lawyering and using common sense, your suggested edit makes the question worse. Asking about a specific example makes the question broader, in that it allows for aircraft- or country-specific answers (Belyakov dies, Brezhnev doesn't like the look, etc.) that don't in fact answer the OP's question. If you narrow the parameters to exclude those answers, you literally get this exact same question, just with extra steps. If you think it's easier to write an answer by taking a specific example and extrapolating, then go ahead and write your answer that way.

@JBH the world i am creating is not alternate history though. There is no USSR in my world. While my world's technological development is similar enough to IRL to talk in terms similar to IRL, the nations, geopolitics. etc are not.

@OT-64SKOT In that case your question should be closed as needs more details. Technological development is intrisically tied to geopolitics. If we don't have Real World geopolitics to work with, then you don't have a question to ask. Delay it as long as you wish in your imaginary world - so long as the technological development required for multi-role fighters is in place when they finally do come along in your imaginary world.

Frame Challenge
This is not a Technology problem. It is a Budget, Doctrine and threat problem.
Why do Multi-Role fighters exist?
Cost
Well, Aircraft and aircraft development is rather costly. Maintaining parts for multiple different types of Aircraft is expensive (although a quick laugh at the promise of the F35 and the parts compatibility between the Marine, Air Force and Navy variants to cut costs...)
An Air Superiority fighter, for example, probably has enough thrust-to-weight and strong enough wings to carry a bomb load - and eventually some bean counter looks at it and asks why we don't try that.
This is how you go from the F15 Eagle having a design doctrine of 'Not a pound for Air-to-Ground' to having the Strike Eagle (AKA The Mud Hen).
So, as long as your nation(s) have sufficient budget (and a population who views air defense as vital to the nation) - then that is your first challenge.
Next up - I am going to combine Doctrine and Threat - because they are essentially two sides of the same coin.
Most Western nations (Except the US...) look at who their likely near-peer adversaries are and what equipment they are running. Almost all are running Export versions of 3rd and 4th generation Fighters.
Something a modern AMRAAM armed jet is going to absolutely chew out of the sky. They dont need to have the absolute pinnacle of Air-to-Air supermaneuvrability - because they have either already taken out the airfields with Tomahawks or they have destroyed the enemy fighters before they were ever detected - When the Iranian F14s took on Iraqi Mig 21 and Mig 23s - they were engaged and destroyed before they the Iraqis knew they were being targetted.
In short - If you are in a race against a person on a Pushbike, taking the family Ute, loaded with your camping gear is fine.
However... If your Near-Peer adversary is every bit as technically competent as you are - now you are in the situation where you need a full-fledged F1 car to race against another F1 car - and all that Camping gear and back seats has to go bye-bye.
Doctrine is a response to a perceived threat. If the Perceived threat needs a specific counter that necessitates that certain compromises have to be made - then you get specialization.
For example - if you believe your enemy has a massively large Bomber fleet - then you would build a large number of Interceptors - where Speed and weapons payload is of the highest priority - you arent going to be dogfighting a strategic bomber. This means things like Low-level performance and Dog fighting performance is compromised to the point where it is not feasible. Like the English Electric Lightning
If you believe your enemy has a highly capable Air superiority fighter, then you are likewise going to build something stealthy, with enough firepower to take on another fighter and extremely agile. Like the F22.
If you believe your enemy has a massive armour advantage and will roll over your borders, then you will build the A10.
In conclusion
Make it so the external threats are specific and require specific problems, make it so the Doctrine is for the Fighters to engage the Fighters, the Interceptors to engage the Bombers, the Ground Attack aircraft to engage the Tanks etc. and...
Make it so your military budget has enough money to pay for all that

Which is actually a very good point - first true multi-role fighter, the F-16, came to be as a supplement to F-15, because - literally - USAF didn't have budget for all F-15s to satisfy all their missions. So they came up with cheaper option. and since it was 1967 when it was first proposed and 1971 when it was came to be, there's not much time left to delay it.

As with anything that you want to get rid of despite it being easy, practical, and cheap:
somebody who has the power to enforce a ban bans the easy, practical, and cheap option
Maybe it's a religious / cultural taboo shared by all the people with the wealth to have air forces. Maybe it's some kind of overarching government that otherwise keeps its hands off. In any case, people still do it, but enough of them get hanged for it that it doesn't become doctrine or a big part of a military procurement budget.
There are all kinds of military technologies that we don't use because of cultural taboos.
For example, forests of spikes with decaying human bodies impaled on them are a great military technology. Cheap, effective, gets the job done. Degrades the heck out of the enemy's will to fight. Amazing. But if you start impaling people on spikes and leaving them all over the place, like any good tactician would, your own side will execute you. Hence Lockheed-Martin doesn't lobby congress to procure overpriced vehicles specialized for person-impalement.

No, I don't think that will work. Proposing a cultural taboo may not apply to other cultures. American culture is rather unique, a lot of it would be - and still (or again) is - incomprehensible for mid-60s Soviets or mid-90s Chinese, even talking about contemporary societies. And whatever else, modern air force is a game of money and resources, otherwise everyone would have modern jetfighters, instead of just 2 types in one country (i do not count sloppy Chinese copy of F-35 as a separate development, nor Su-57 is true 5G fighter, BTW). Money is the key.

I have a hard time seeing this as plausible. Sure, cultural taboos exist, though they tend to be ignored if military necessity is strong enough. You can imagine a taboo that bans nuclear weapons, or poison gas, or dropping napalm from planes. But given that the OP explicitly wants specialized attack, bomber, interceptor aircraft, it's hard to justify a taboo that says you can do those things, you just have to do them from different planes.
